# Splitting an NSString

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have the following code which fetches a string from an array of strings and splits the string into 2 parts.

```
NSString *temp = [tableViewData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSArray *tempArray = [temp componentsSeparatedByString: @"_"];
cell.textLabel.text = [tempArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

and the String which is added is as follows

```
newTitle = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d_%@",[Daily_QuoteViewController counter],title];
[plistArray addObject:newTitle];
[plistArray writeToFile:filepath atomically: YES];
```

Which is adding an index and a string.

I am trying to then split that string in the first code section. but trying to access the second part of the string at index 1 gives an out of bounds error.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSArray objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'

What is the best way to split the string in order to use both parts of the string

split firstPart_secondPart

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code is ok. I assume that temp does not hold a string as you expect - can you check that?

Comment: temp is a string. I can see that it adds to the array, it reads the array into the table view, but when trying to split, and use it I get an out of bounds error.

Comment: It finds the 0 index, but not the index 1, for the second half of the string. advice please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems fine to me. Can you print out NSString temp? `NSLog(@"%@", temp);`

Comment: I found the error, the only test String I had in the plist didnt contain "_" . Forgot to look there. silly mistake. thanks for your time all.